# How to set alternate URL in retrofit android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I Have implemented the node js rest API. That being use in my android app with the help of Retrofit. Now. If my app is in production and then somehow my main server will be crash. So, in that case I have a backup server that will work same as the main server do.

> So, How can I set an alternate base URL in retrofit android? So, If the main URL does not work then call all API from that alternate URL. Is there any build-it functionality?

Or most welcome for suggestions, Any other alternative ways to implement this.

Comment: Did you try onError() or onFail()?

Comment: Is there any built-in functionality?

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand your question.

Comment: Is Retrofit provide function to achieve this? Because I can set manually with help error type while calling API. But, If retrofit can provide that then it will more awesome code for me.

Comment: You only repeated yourself. No idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion for you.

A NodeJS server should not stop for no reason. Most of the time, it's because of a 500 Error that have not been catched and stop the server. So, at first, make sure that every js command that may cause error is inside try/catch block.

Then, I suggest using of PM2 package

This is the best option to run on a production server.

It has several advantages:

- It's easy to setup and run.
- PM2 will automatically restart your application if it crashes.
- PM2 will keep a log of your unhandled exceptions - in this case, in a
  file at /home/safeuser/.pm2/logs/app-err.log.
- With one command, PM2 can ensure that any applications it manages
  restart when the server reboots. Basically meaning your node
  application will start as a service.

ref: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Comment: Currently, I'm using pm2 for production and it is running on a google compute engine VM. But, somehow compute engine will not work then pm2 will stop for that stipulated time. In that stipulated time I want to use another VM which will be already running same as the main VM.